# cocoa format NSURL string for gmail atom feed

Tags: cocoa, encoding, gmail

I'm trying to format a url string to retrieve a gmail atom feed but I'm having problems with it. Here's my code:

```
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@gmail.google.com/­gmail/­feed/atom", username, userpass];
NSString *encodedString = [urlstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

Here's what's in my log.

```
https://••••••••@gmail.com:•••••••••@gmail.google.com/%C2%ADgmail/%C2%ADfeed/atom
```

This-->%C2%AD seems to be the problem. It should just be a slash. Any idea how to clean that up? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Your `urlstring` contains soft hyphens.

**Comprehensive answer:**

In the following code `withSoftHyphens` and `withoutSoftHyphens` look equal:

```
NSString *withSoftHyphens    = @"example/­example/­example";
NSString *withoutSoftHyphens = @"example/example/example";

NSLog(@"%@",[withSoftHyphens    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"%@",[withoutSoftHyphens stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

The output is however different:
 
*(checkout yourself by copying and executing the code above)*

```
"example/%C2%ADexample/%C2%ADexample"
"example/example/example"
```

The soft hyphens are basically represented by `%C2%AD` after encoding the string.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> Soft hyphen is a type of hyphen used to specify a place in text where
>   a hyphenated break is allowed without forcing a line break in an
>   inconvenient place if the text is re-flowed.

In other words, your `urlstring` contains soft hyphens.
Simply remove `/­g` and `/­f` using the backspace key and type them again.
Notice you actually need THREE backspaces to only remove two characters (`/­g`).
- The first backspace removes the `g`.
- The second backspace removes the invisible soft hyphen.
- The third backspace removes the `/`.

In conclusion, your code works just fine after removing the soft hyphens:

```
NSString *username = @"Anne";
NSString *userpass = @"Password";
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@gmail.google.com/mail/feed/atom", username, userpass];
NSString *encodedString = [urlstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

Output:

```
https://Anne:Password@gmail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
```

Comment: Thanks for the really informative post. Arghh, there's just too much out there to know. : D